# Hints to integrate complex quantity

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Can someone provide me with hints to integrate $e^zdz$ where |z|=1. I have tried taking z equals $cos\theta+isin\theta$, but it became cumbersome. Best way seems $z=e^{i\theta}$. But I am unsure how to raise e to the power of each  to integrate. Please help

Comment: Are you familiar with Cauchy integral formula? If so, take $f(z)=ze^z$.

Comment: Does the integration extend over the entire unit circle?  If so, Cauchy's Integral Theorem guarantees   $$\oint_{|z|=1}e^z\,dz=0$$